# Image array in android

Tags: android, image

I am trying to use an array of images then set my ImageView to one of the images in the array.
My first instinct was to use an array of strings with the image names but this did not work.

How do I do this.Make a drawable array with the image names without quotes or what?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

depends where your images are

but if there a in R.drawables. then why not simply store the int reference in your array and then load that

if you want to do treatment on them you can also open the Bitmap and store that

edit:

```
  private int[] textureArrayWin = {
R.drawable.star_00,
R.drawable.star_01,
R.drawable.star_02,
};
```

and now you have a table of the id of the images you want

Comment: Hi, They are in the drawable-mdpi folder.Not sure what you mean by storing the int reference in my array and then loading that.Really knew to android.

Comment: That was not the question

Answer (score 3):

Yes you could create an array of drawables.

As an alternate you could also create an array of ints which map to your resource ids. So drop your images in the drawable folder which gives them resource IDs.

```
R.drawable.yourimage1
R.drawable.yourimage2
...
R.drawable.yourimagen
```

Then when you want to load an image and draw to your imageview you do something like this from your Activity. Assuming "yourarray" is the array:

```
Drawable d = getResources().getDrawable(yourarray[n]);
```

Then I believe the call is setImageDrawable on ImageView. So:

```
yourImageView.setImageDrawable(d);
```

Comment: Go with the alternate solution rreeverb describes. You don't have to 'get' the drawable, you can simply set the image resource ID on the view! http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#setImageResource(int)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the resources from drawable-mdpi and store them in an array of integers like

```
private static final Integer[] Icons = {
    R.drawable.bg_android_icon,
    R.drawable.bg_sunrise_icon,
    R.drawable.bg_sunset_icon,
    ......
};
```

And then you can use it in a loop with Postion ranging from 0 to Icons.length and set it to `ImageView`

```
ImageView.setBackground=getResources().getDrawable(Icons[Position]);
```