# How to load images from url array to image array?

Tags: android, picasso

I have an url array and I have to load all images and put it in image array.

I'm trying this

```
ImageView tempImageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.temp_image_view);
        for (int j = 0; j < urls.length-1; j++){
            Picasso.with(getApplicationContext()).load(urls[j]).into(tempImageView);
            image[j] = tempImageView.getDrawable();

        }
```

but it's doesn't work. how can I do it?

Comment: Look at : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4201879/image-array-in-android

Comment: The point behind using Picasso is to load images *asynchronously*. `tempImageView` will not have an image by the time that you call `getDrawable()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Picasso has an oncompletion listener.

Check this answer

[How to listen for Picasso (Android) load complete events?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26548660/how-to-listen-for-picasso-android-load-complete-events)